# INDIRECTO + FILA + INDICE + UNICOS

Tags: excel, formulas

Estoy intentando obtener de una columna dentro de mi rango de tabla el valor único máximo de la columna.

Mi objetivo es básicamente obtener un valor dinámico, de modo que cuando el usuario filtre la columna de "YEAR INFORME" ese valor se muestre en mi titulo, para así obtener algo parecido a un título dinámico.

No obstante, la columna tendrá siempre el mismo valor, pero obviamente duplicada, de allí la idea de usar la función único.

Mi columna es está:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi intención es poder mostrar el año seleccionado de mi columna en cuestión cada vez que se seleccionen un año de la columna para que me  lo muestre en el titulo del informe, así la persona puede leer el año del informe que está consultando, siendo 2023 el año en cuestión, tal que se vea así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy usando esta formula:

=INDIRECTO("DATO_BASE!A" & FILA(INDICE(UNICOS(DATO_BASE!$A$2:$A$108); 1)))

sin embargo me arroja un error de tipo Valor

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He comprobado que el tipo de dato de la columna sea texto, aunque no estoy muy segura que problema puede ser.

¿A alguien se le ocurre que puede ser el error?
Además, agradecería una alternativa para hacer lo mismo de manera más simplificada.

Os agradezco de antemano cualquier ayuda.

Un saludo.

Comment: Buen día, si alguna respuesta te sirvió por favor acéptala, así ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a sus preguntas y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. Lectura recomendada [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo he logrado lo que buscas manteniendo la columna numérica y usando la función `subtotal()`, a la que paso como parámetros 4 (valor máximo) y la columna o el rango de datos de la columna en la tabla, y luego convirtiendo el dato a cadena con la función `text()`, así:

```
="Solicitudes emitidas en el año "&TEXT(SUBTOTAL(4; Table1[@Año]); "0")
```

Acá tengo filtrado el año 2016:

[image: Filtrado el año 2016]

Cambio el filtro:

[image: Cambiando el filtro a 2020]

Clic en aceptar, y produce el resultado deseado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Jaja encontramos casi la misma solución, solo una observación, según me parece el `4` incluye las filas ocultas y el `104` excluye las filas ocultas, probé también con `4` y ahora lo que no entiendo es porque ambas soluciones funcionan.

Comment: jaja, eso veo. Siempre he usado 4 para el max. La diferencia no está en filas filtradas, sino ocultas. Subtotal nunca incluye las filas filtradas, sino la diferencia está en filas ocultas (sub/menú hide&unhide del comando format)

Comment: @HeytalePazguato [este menú](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOY1M.png)

Comment: Ah ya veo, al leer la documentación lo que yo entendí era que las filas mostradas en la tabla y pensé que las ocultas se refería a las que habían sido excluidas por el filtro, por eso puse el `104` en mi respuesta.

Comment: Bueno, cada día se aprende algo nuevo. :)

Comment: Muchísimas gracias a los dos, me habéis salvado horas de averiguar el problema u alternativas para el mismo fin. Esto es lo que hace de este foro una nueva herramienta :) Saludos y buen día @jachguate y HeytalePazguato no me permite tag a 2 usuarios

Answer (score 1):

Buen día,

Lo puedes hacer con la función [`SUBTOTAL`](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/office/funci%C3%B3n-subtotales-7b027003-f060-4ade-9040-e478765b9939) o su equivalente en el lenguaje de Excel que estes utilizando (Yo lo uso en inglés).

Teniendo la siguiente tabla con datos genéricos:

| Col1 | Year |
| --- | --- |
| a | 2020 |
| b | 2021 |
| c | 2022 |
| d | 2023 |
| e | 2020 |
| f | 2021 |
| g | 2022 |
| h | 2023 |

En la celda donde quieras mostrar el valor máximo con respecto a las celdas visibles de tu tabla escribes la siguiente fórmula

```
=SUBTOTAL(104, Table1[Year])
```

El `104` significa máximo.

El nombre de la tabla `Table1` debe corresponder con el nombre que hayas dado a tu tabla. Si seleccionas todos lo datos de tu tabla sin la fila de los nombres de las columnas puedes ver el nombre que tiene tu tabla.

[image: Obtener nombre de la tabla]

Lo que va entre corchetes, en mi ejemplo `Year` es el nombre de tu columna.

Ejemplo de funcionamiento al seleccionar el filtro 2021:

[image: Ejemplo del funcionamiento]